# Frequency of hanzi by use in Chinese words

Tags: vocabulary, characters

I can easily find a lot of lists with the most frequently used hanzi. But I think the frequency is linked to the use in sentences, independently of words.

I need the frequency of used hanzi linked to the construction of Chinese words. I mean the frequency for 的 will be very different. If someone has an idea for the frequency of use of radicals in the construction of hanzi, I am also interested.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you would like to see. Please elaborate your question more precisely or give a detailed example.

Comment: i mean 的 often appears in a full text, but not so often in meaningful words, like 的话. so a list of frequently found characters in a text should be quite different than a list of frequently found characters in a dictionary !
about radicals : 的 has 白 as radical, how many words have 白 as radical ?
which are the radicals used for the biggest number of words ?
is it cleared now ?

Comment: So you are looking for character frequency based on text corpora? Take a look at this list: http://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/listchangyong.php (But the data is based on corpora that are more than 10 years old).

Comment: thank you, if i can consider " the current Modern Chinese Corpus, including both informative and imaginative texts " as a dictionary or a list of meaningful words, this is exactly what i was looking for !

what about radicals and hanzis ? the most frequently used radicals in hanzis  ?

Comment: You need to look for a list that assigns the radical to characters and combine that list with the one linked above. Wikipedia has one such list at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aChinese_characters_decomposition , but you will also find another one at https://cjkdecomp.codeplex.com/ .

Comment: I haven't explored the second source, the Wikimedia list is quite large and contains more than just the radicals, you can however transform it into a list of [characters + radicals] with Excel, Python or another programming language or tool of your choice. If you want to know the most frequent list of radicals occurring in texts, you can combine this list with the character frequency list linked above.

Comment: @faure BTW, the plural of hanzi is just hanzi, no 's'.

Comment: @FangJing  hanzi is english word, if more than one should take a s !
but english is not my mother's langage, so maybe you're right :-)

Answer (score 3):

You would need to do some database manipulation. First extract a bigram frequency list (http://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/) or a more general word frequency list (as provided by Wenlin, for example), and then decompose the individual morphemes to obtain the most used characters for words.

Comment: have you any link for a more general word frequency list ? it can help.
i am not interested by bigram which may be a nonsense combination of characters. only bigram or trigram ( or 4 like 自动取款 ) which are words ( defined as words, verbs, adjectives, adverbs...) which can be used in crosswords puzzles  :-)

Comment: The answer given contains both bigram and character frequency list, in Ancient and Modern Chinese, and in various types of texts. It seems sufficient for your answer.

Comment: it is written " Note: A bigram may be a nonsense combination of characters.  " i am not interested by these bigrams without meaning. english is not my mother language, i do not understand the purpose of this table. can 一个 be found in a dictionary ? this  is not a word for me, perapera does not consider this bigram as a meaningful word :-)

Comment: but i admit i can remove nonsense words ( they seem to be not so numerous ) and search alone hanzis and get my informations :-)
perapera is a fantastic tool !

Comment: @faure If you only need bigrams that are actually meaningful, use the CC-CEDICT dictionary file at http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cc-cedict , it contains 100k+ words, including about 12k+ unique characters, the rest are 2+ character words.

Comment: i do not like this template, because do not find where or how thank to the answer !
this is far from ergonomic :-(

Comment: @faure Nevermind, are you developing an app or similar? Or you need the data for research?

Comment: i am not developping software, i am not working in research. i am just learning chinese and looking for any help.
i didn't know wenlin, this is a good tool with perepera, pleco, hanping pro, memrise.com and chineseskill  :-) 
great thank to @倪阔乐

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any existing statistics online so I wrote a simple program to do the job. Source data was downloaded from SouGou web dictionary 2006(see [here](http://www.sogou.com/labs/dl/w.html)), a vocabulary consists of a totality of 468,949 words.

Since you don't need this for research purposes I will only list partial results below. If you need the whole list of 6,143 characters just leave a comment, I'll see if I can find a site to host the file...

note that repetitive characters are counted separately in a word(e.g. for the word '一心一意', '一' is counted twice)

In the form of

characters    frequencies

1. 不   4268
2. 人   3176
3. 一   2961
4. 大   2808
5. 中   2108
6. 之   1811
7. 国   1809
8. 机   1800
9. 学   1773
10. 心   1759
11. 无   1678
12. 子   1675
13. 生   1664
14. 天   1630
15. 网   1549
16. 小   1497
17. 有   1486
18. 电   1444
19. 上   1421
20. 水   1396
21. 地   1309
22. 三   1306
23. 下   1301
24. 风   1291
25. 文   1270
26. 行   1266
27. 业   1262
28. 会   1260
29. 工   1237
30. 发   1231
31. 新   1228
32. 家   1225
33. 高   1194
34. 金   1183
35. 性   1134
36. 了   1126
37. 出   1124
38. 理   1072
39. 动   1058
40. 公   1044
41. 自   1034
42. 手   1032
43. 山   1029
44. 头   1008
45. 成   1002
46. 日   1001
47. 化   986
48. 道   985
49. 车   983
50. 十   933

As for the radicals, you'll first have to specify the writing system for the characters, as traditional characters usually have much more radicals than their simplified counterparts.(for instance, '一' and '壹', former one being simplified and latter traditional)

Comment: thank you so much ! that's exactly what i was looking for. with wenlin ( a wonderful tool for these stats ) i could verify that 不 is used in 4829 words, and 中 in 1221 words.
it will help me a lot. so i was right concerning 的 which is used in only 1249 words.
however, the same list reduced to a list of more frequents words ( even chinese people do not use 400000 words ) should be very interesting for any chinese learner :-)

Comment: hello ! i would like to know if it is possible for you to run your " simple program " on the vocabulary required to get HSK level 6, and the result for the most frequently used characters ( almost 300 first )
HSK list is available here : http://chinwa.fr/hsk/liste-du-vocabulaire-hsk-6-5000-mots/#.VzBZWnqxX3h  :-)
maybe another list would be more convenient to your program ?

Comment: @faure Sorry for the late reply. Since I used an unregistered account I wasn't able to recieve any notification of your comments, nor am I allowed to add comment below my previous answer... Anyway, yes it is possible to run the program on your given input. The result in HTML format is hosted and downloadable via [this page](https://www.datafilehost.com/d/040968e3). Hopefully it would still prove useful to you despite long overdue(again sorry for that).

Comment: @MasterYoda Are you user13324? If so, you can merge your two accounts, go to [this page](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @MasterYoda  thank you, but you gave the link for a program ! how can i use it ?

Comment: @faure try this:
open that link I gave you, and click 'download' on that page, that should direct you to an advertisement page which asks you to install an add-on toobar, at this point click **Skip** (NOT 'Add and Start Download'), and use the link below to download that html file.

Comment: @MasterYoda  thank you, but when i click " dowload " i do not go to your advertising page, i download char count.exe !  this is not a .html page

Comment: @faure Nevermind, I've uploaded it on another site, [here](http://www.filedropper.com/charcount) is the link. Please pardon the inconveniences as I've been limited to a handful of choices for file hosting services that are not blocked by my country's national firewall.

Comment: it works fine :-)